# Vuex state not updating, state.dispatch no being called

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am using Vue and a Vuex store in a project.

Here's the **Vuex store**

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        inventoryPageNumber: 0,
        inventoryPageCount: 0,
    },
    getters: {
        getinventoryPageNumber: state => {
            return state.inventoryPageNumber;
        },

        getinventoryPageCount: state => {
            return state.inventoryPageCount;
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        setinventoryPageNumber(state, pagenumber) {
            state.inventoryPageNumber = pagenumber
        },

        setinventoryPageCount(state, pagecount) {
            state.inventoryPageCount = pagecount
        }
    },
    actions: {
        patchinventoryPageNumber(context, pagenumber) {
            context.commit('setinventoryPageNumber', pagenumber)
        },

        patchinventoryPageCount(context, pagecount) {
            context.commit('setinventoryPageCount', pagecount)
        },

    }
})
```

And this is where it is being used in **component**:

```
**Tempalate**
      <button class="fa fa-backward fa-xs text-white button-trans" @click="firstPage" :disabled="pageNumber==0" aria-hidden="true"></button>

<span class="text-white pl-2 pr-2">Page {{pageNumber+1}} of {{pageCount}}</span>
**Script**

computed:{
   pageCount: {
      get() {
        let count = Math.ceil(this.products.length / this.size);
        return count;
      },
      set(newValue) {
        store.dispatch("patchinventoryPageCount", newValue);
      }
    }
},

methods: {
    firstPage() {
      this.pageNumber = 0;
      store.dispatch("setinventoryPageNumber", this.pageNumber);
    }
}
```

**Expected**

> PageCount to be updated as calculation being done and Page Number to update on click

**Actual**

> Local computed property gets updated, state doesn't
>
> store.dispatch is not being called

Comment: From where you are using `pageCount ` computed property?

Comment: pageCount is being calculated using a prop products: Array

Comment: Can you share the codes where `pageCount` is calculated?

Comment: @SajibKhan it's already there shared

Comment: I meant, from where you are invoking `pageCount` computed property.. (from the template or else)?

Comment: in template, wait i add that

Comment: @SajibKhan added in template

Comment: Do you initialize `pageNumber ` in `data()`? also do you see any error or working now?

Answer (score 0):

You are dispatching to the wrong action. Change:

```
store.dispatch("setinventoryPageNumber", this.pageNumber);
```

to

```
store.dispatch("patchinventoryPageNumber", this.pageNumber);
```

Comment: It works when i click on the component in Vue Dev tools, otherwise it don't